# How Multiple inheritance in php

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance, extends

I know, we do not have concept of multiple inheritance in php.
so is there any alternative ?

example: class1 is combination of class2 and class3

i cannot use

```
 class1 extends class2,class3
```

so how should i use ?

```
 class2 extends class3;
 class1 extends class2;
```

not sure so asking for help ?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. A different inheritance hierarchy may be the answer, yes. Or maybe traits. Or maybe composition. There's no *general* answer.

Comment: If you are using php 5.4+ try to read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Check traits: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Simulating-Multiple-Inheritance-With-PHP-Traits.html